# Java Swing - Condition SQL Queries

Tags: java, sql, swing

I've a sql select statement to display the query on my jtable via jButton by getting the user input info from jComboBox & jDateChooser.

Is it possible to set conditions to the buttons e.g

Code below for jButton action lisener

```
    java.util.Date dateFromDateChooser = jDateChooser.getDate();
    String dateString = String.format("%1$tY-%1$tm-%1$td", dateFromDateChooser);  

    String attendant = (String) cbName.getSelectedItem();
    String fill = "SELECT id as 'No', recDate as 'Date', super as 'Supervisor', attendant as 'Attendant' from log"
            + "WHERE recDate = '"+dateString+"'"
            + "and attendant = '" + attendant + "'";

    try{

        ps = conn.prepareStatement(fill);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();    
        jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```

}
The above code is working fine, but I wish to allow user to either 2 types of conditions.
Such as display search results by selecting either "Date and jComboBox" or just "Date"

Can I user if else statement for this case?

Please advice...

[image]

Comment: Yes it is possible. If you clarify your question, we may in fact be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query without attendant if name not selected

```
String attendant = (String) cbName.getSelectedItem();
    String qry;
    if( attendant != null && !attendant.isEmpty() ) {
     qry = "SELECT id as 'No', recDate as 'Date', super as 'Supervisor', attendant as 'Attendant' from log"
            + "WHERE recDate = '"+dateString+"'"
            + "and attendant = '" + attendant + "'";
    } else {
        qry = "SELECT id as 'No', recDate as 'Date', super as 'Supervisor', attendant as 'Attendant' from log"
            + "WHERE recDate = '"+dateString+"'";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a check to your SQL building

```
String fill = "SELECT id as 'No', recDate as 'Date', super as 'Supervisor', attendant as 'Attendant' from log"
        + "WHERE recDate = '"+dateString+"'";

if(comboboxShouldBeIncluded) {
        fill+= " and attendant = '" + attendant + "'";
}
```

Comment: Possible give me example how to give a checking for if(comboboxShouldBeIncluded) {
        fill+= " and attendant = '" + attendant + "'";
}